# How to remove extra padding at top of window?

Tags: android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have this strange padding-top when I run my App on Android. On iOS it  looks as expected.

When I check the padding is 0 for all directions. My last thought is that it could be related to some of my layouts, but I don't understand what that could be.

Toolbar layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
```

Tabs layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

I am using Xamarin.Form's MasterDetailPage with my pages being ContentPage. 
Does this combination of pages create this error on Android? Please help me fix it.

Here is a screenshot of what I see:

[image: [Example]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTQ1u.png)

Comment: That's the space for the ActionBar. Try adding <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> to your theme in your styles.xml.

Comment: @HeisenBerg

    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">0dp</item>

not work, still error...
i use this perent "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
and nothing changed

Comment: try adding <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item> to your styles.xml

Answer (score 0):

You're able to change lots of settings in Android Solution (MainActivity.cs) just underneath your namespace.

For example:

```
 [Activity(Theme = "@style/AppStyle.Light", Label = "ProjectName", MainLauncher = false,
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```